# Sync OpenLDAP - Active Directory

Tags: ldap, active-directory, openldap, domain

Today, we have an OpenLDAP that works very well.

We would like to create a Domain & AD (**Windows**) that would be populated and synchronized by OpenLDAP.

I could read some topics for reverse situations (AD synchronization on an OpenLDAP).
Which situation would you advise me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Samba AD domain controller and manually sync with a separate OpenLDAP instance. Scripting can help with syncing.

You should take a look at the official Samba docs to get a better feel if it would work for you:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

Comment: I was not able to get the Samba AD DC to use an existing external LDAP, which is why I suggested scripting the sync.

Comment: As far as what this approach allows is the most helpful thing: synchronized credentials. You can provide file shares separately through use of ACLs (for permissions control) and Samba+NFS shares.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I don't want to use AD Samba for just one reason:
Samba 4 can be AD but is at most compatible with Windows Server 2012 with a Windows 2008 R2 level.
Windows Server 2012 is at the end of normal support. The most sustainable situation will be to implement a Windows Server 2016/2019.

The idea would be to synchronize (with a script?) all the accounts on the OpenLDAP in the Windows Active Directory, in a secure way, 2 or 3 times / day.